# React add new item to a table

Tags: reactjs, forms, jsx

I'm working on a React project. I need to add new data to a table using a form. In here when I run 'npm start' command it will show 'Audi' in the list. But when I trying to add new vehicle brand it will not adding. There are no errors showing. Can anyone solve this problem.

This is my vehicleType.jsx file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";
import {FormGroup,Form,Input,Col} from "reactstrap";

class VehicleType extends Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        items : ['Audi']
      }
  
    }
  
   
    addItem(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      const {items} =this.state;
      const newItem = this.newItem.value;
  
      this.setState({
        items : [...this.state.items,newItem]
      })
  
    }


    render() {
        const { items } = this.state;
        return ( 
          <>
            
            <Form onSubmit={(e) => {this.addItem(e)}}>
                <Row>
                    <Col md="3">
                        <FormGroup className="has-success">
                              <Input ref={(input) => this.newItem =input } className="is-valid" placeholder="Add" type="text"/>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="4">
                        <Button color="primary" size="lg" type="submit" >
                          Add new vehicle brand
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Form>
                        
                        
            <Table className="align-items-center" responsive>
                        
                <tbody>
                    {
                        items.map(item => {
                        return(
                          <tr key = {item}>
                            <th scope="row" col-md-2>
                              <span className="mb-0 text-sm">
                              {item}
                              </span>
                            </th>
                          </tr>
                        )}
                    }
                </tbody>
            </Table>
    
    </>
    );
  }
}
export default VehicleType;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's some issue with the reactstrap on the ref they provide here is the working sandbox for your requirement
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-einstein-f9pc3?file=/src/index.js)

if you still need to use reactstrap then you need to go with state variable like

```
<Input onChange={handleInputChange} value={this.state.addValue} className="is-valid" placeholder="Add" type="text"/>
```

in the handleChange add this

```
handleInputChange(e){
this.setState({addValue:e.target.value})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
addItem(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const {items} =this.state;
  items.push(this.newItem.value) 
  this.setState({ items })  
}
```